# Explode one line to multiple in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I have a table looks like this:

```
product    price99    price100
A          2          1
B          3          2
..
```

I don't know how to do that in MySQL to explode that into a format like this, like using the melt and cast function in R.

```
product     quantity_min    quantity_max    price
A           1               99              2
A           100             999999          1
B           1               99              3
B           100             999999          2
..
```

I have a feeling that it might need [case](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) statement? but really having a hard time making it work. What can I try next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this like

```
select 
    product, 
    1 as 'quantity_min', 
    99 as 'quantity_max', 
    price99 as 'price'
FROM Table1
UNION ALL
select 
    product, 
    100 as 'quantity_min', 
    999999 as 'quantity_max', 
    price100 as 'price'
FROM Table1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below case statement:

```
SELECT 
    product,
    CASE WHEN quantity_min = 1 THEN 1 ELSE quantity_min * 100 - 99 END AS quantity_min,
    CASE WHEN quantity_min = 1 THEN 99 ELSE quantity_min * 100 - 1 END AS quantity_max,
    price99 AS price
FROM 
    your_table
UNION
SELECT 
    product,
    CASE WHEN quantity_min = 1 THEN 100 ELSE quantity_min * 100 END AS quantity_min,
    999999 AS quantity_max,
    price100 AS price
FROM 
    your_table;
```